# how to retrieve data from ArrayList in JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm working on a `J2EE` project and I'm using the `struts2` framework. I want to retrieve a list of connected gamers from my action '`gamerConnected`'. In this code below, i wanted just to display each gamer username to know whether each loop works or not. It displays the message below in the alert. I can't get the usernames. Any help would be much appreciated

> Gamers : undefined

**Console.log**

```
{"Gamers":[{"passWord":"madox002","userName":"madox"},
{"passWord":"Yohan002","userName":"Yohan"}]}
```

*Note: Gamers is the name of the list of gamers in my action.*

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.getJSON("gamerConnected", function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            $.each(data, function(index, item){
                alert(index+" : "+item.userName);

            });
        })
    }, 5000)
})
```

Comment: Just a typo in the JS code.

Answer (score 1):

The objects containing usernames and passwords are in `data.Gamers`, not `data`. So change it to:

```
$.each(data.Gamers, function(index, item) {
    alert(index+" : "+item.userName);
});
```